# Matplotlib: plot the entire column values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following data frame `my_df`:

```
        my_1     my_2     my_3
--------------------------------
0         5       7        4
1         3       5       13
2         1       2        8
3        12       9        9
4         6       1        2
```

I want to make a plot where x-axis is categorical values with my_1, my_2, and my_3. y-axis is integer. For each column in `my_df`, I want to plot all its 5 values at x = my_i. What kind of plot should I use in matplotlib? Thanks!

Comment: Asking for charts can be the worst because you know what you want in your head but you don't have a good way to communicate that to us.  However, you can draw a picture on a piece of paper and take a photo with your phone and load that up to the question.  Unless of course, unutbu has already answered your question. (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a bar chart:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_1': [5, 3, 1, 12, 6], 'my_2': [7, 5, 2, 9, 1], 'my_3': [4, 13, 8, 9, 2]})

df.T.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

or a scatter plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_1': [5, 3, 1, 12, 6], 'my_2': [7, 5, 2, 9, 1], 'my_3': [4, 13, 8, 9, 2]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cols = np.arange(len(df.columns))
x = np.repeat(cols, len(df))
y = df.values.ravel(order='F')
color = np.tile(np.arange(len(df)), len(df.columns))
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=150, c=color)
ax.set_xticks(cols)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter)
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(len(df)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Just for fun, here is how to make the same scatter plot using Pandas' `df.plot`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_1': [5, 3, 1, 12, 6], 'my_2': [7, 5, 2, 9, 1], 'my_3': [4, 13, 8, 9, 2]})

columns = df.columns
index = df.index
df = df.stack()
df.index.names = ['color', 'column']
df = df.rename('y').reset_index()
df['x'] = pd.Categorical(df['column']).codes
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', c='color', colorbar=True, 
             cmap='viridis', s=150)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(columns)))
ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
cbar = ax.collections[-1].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks(index)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, it requires quite a bit of DataFrame manipulation just to call
`df.plot` and then there are some extra matplotlib calls needed to set the tick
marks on the scatter plot and colorbar. Since Pandas is not saving effort here,
I would go with the first (NumPy/matplotlib) approach shown above.

Comment: I would prefer each number is a dot, instead of a bar. Is that possible?